# How can I prevent sitewide SQL Injection for good?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, forms

A client of mine has a website that has been overly hacked in the passed days. The method the hacker is using is unknown, however I have managed to secure almost everything except for matters regarding SQL Injection.

The problem is that the source code of the website is very messy and it has lots and lots of forms which are all unprotected from SQL Injection.

What I have thought as a solution is to prevent any form submitted within the website to be processed before being checked. It would be checked from within the main "index.php" file which redirects every request made on the website to it's needed controllers and models.

**What I need is a good PHP script (or help me by guiding me into writing this code) to process all the submitted forms ($_GET and $_POST) and find out if the user is trying to submit any "sql" data and if so log that request and deny the form from being submitted.**

This is the part of the index.php I will be putting this code:

```
public function load_controller()
{

    $controller_name = $this->uri['controller'];
    $action = $this->uri['action'];
    $param = $this->uri['param'];
    $model = $this->uri['model'];
    $controller_name = ucwords($controller_name);
    $file = ROOT.DS.'admin'.DS.'controller'.DS."$controller_name".'_controller.php';
    if(file_exists($file))
    {

        require_once($file) ; 

        $controller = new $controller_name(); 

        if(method_exists($controller,$action))
        {

            $controller->{$action}($param[0],$param[1],$param[2],$param[3],
        $param[4],$param[5],$param[6],$param[7]);   
        }
        else
        {
            define('HEADER_SENT', '/router.php?num=404');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        define('HEADER_SENT', '/router.php?num=404');
    }
}
```

**of course if you think this is not a good solution please tell me what your idea is and please have in mind that we have limited time in resolving this issue.**

Thanks :)

Comment: This isn't remotely an sql injection.

Comment: The code above is not an sql injection, I want to place the new code besides (on top) this code to prevent characters related to sql injection being processed from the forms that are submitted throughout the whole website.

Comment: Just use parametrized queries. Then you don't have to worry about SQL injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To try and parse input is a fool's game. You'll never get it right until you have written a complete database engine, and you say time is of the essence. So why bother? The only foolproof way is to completely remove the opportunity for any user input.

The correct approach is with parameterised queries and/or stored procedures, or alternatively, some kind of ORM approach, which correctly implemented, is just an abstraction of the above.

Comment: +1 There will be no other correct answer than parameterised queries.